# How to port an ES6 require() statement to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript2.0, porting

We have been able to ported all the code for from JS/ES6 project to typescript 3.x but we can't seem to get the following file ported correctly.

The short version of file looks like this:

index.js (original):

```
export const Log = require('./src/Log');
export const OidcClient = require('./src/OidcClient');

export default {
    Log,
    OidcClient
};
```

index.ts (ported):

```
import Log from './src/Log';
import { OidcClient } from './src/OidcClient';

export default {
    Log,
    OidcClient
};
```

The problem appears to be with the `import LOG from './src/Log'` vs. the `export const Log = require('./src/Log');` statement. If we change the source file to use `export LOG from './src/Log';` then the `Log` is undefined in the calling script file, just like the problem we are seeing in the ported version.

Intellisense, for the source file, states that the exported `OidcClient` statement is defined as 
`(property) OidcClient: typeof import("c:/.../src/OidcClient").`

Whereas the ported version of the `OidcClient` statement is defined as
`(property) OidcClient: typeof OidcClient`.

How do we make this work from a TypeScript file?

Comment: Shouldn't how you import `LOG` be the same as the other one? They were originally and from your question it seems as if `OidcClient` is working correctly?

Comment: `Log` is undefined because you imported `LOG`, is there a reason you changed the name? Unless you plan on taking advantage of module defaults and object desctructuring syntax, then you can use something like this `import * as Log from './src/Log';`

Comment: Notice that `require` has nothing to do with ES6. It's part of the CommonJs module standard, as used e.g. in node.

Comment: Please show the code of how `./src/Log` and `./src/OidcClient` export the values

Comment: @pmkro no Log and OidcClient had the same issues.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger sorry Log vs LOG was just a typo while composing the question.

Comment: @Bergi correct, the file was being processed by a simple nodes server. But unfortunately the results weren't the same.

Comment: @Kabuo can you update the question to remove the typos? it would be helpful for other users who may stumble upon your question.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger good idea, thanks. Typo now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For completeness**

We are using webpack and built the output as a library, with these output settings:

`libraryTarget: 'var',
library:'Oidc'`

Thus the JS client should use the module like: `Oidc.Log.Error(message)`. But the problem was `Oidc.Log` is undefine.

**The clue**

In the browser's debugger we noticed that `Oidc` is defined as a `Module`, which is what we expected, but it had a mysterious property called `default` which had everything we wanted within it. Okay, how to remove the `default` property and apply everything in it's part object, the `Oidc` module?

After 4 days of trial and error, we found the solution.

**Solution**

The documentation, and everything we could find, stated we should use:

`export default { Log, OidcClient }`

Out of desperation we finally tried removing the `default` keyword, as in:

`export { Log, OidcClient }`

and guess what? It worked!!

No more mysterious `default` property and all the types live off of the `Oidc` module as expected!

Comment: This does not explain why `export default` suddenly stopped working when you switched to Typescript. How did removing`default` suddenly fix your issue? The only common declaration between the code snippets was the `export default` declaration, so that really seems like an unlikely suspect if the code was working before.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger because in the `Oidc` module we no longer had the magic property called `default`. Why TypeScript was adding this property I have no idea, but it wasn't there in the JS version.